# Compiles but does not run Error: could not find or load main class

Tags: java, windows

My problem is compilation part works perfectly, but while running the Java program I get this error saying "Could not find or load main class".

This is where the files is located

```
C:\JenaAdapter\examples\Test.java
```

I try to compile the file from another folder where my JAR are located

```
C:\JenaAdapter\Jar> javac -classpath abc.jar;123.jar;xyz.jar ./../examples/Test.java
```

Compiles perfectly. Now when I try to run

```
C:\JenaAdapter\Jar> java -classpath pqr.jar;tvs.jar;abc.jar;123.jar;xyz.jar ./../examples/Test
```

gives the error

Answer (score 1):

Test.class is the file. File location has nothing to do with classpath.
Put your class file to the classpath and use classpath to determine the path.

In other words, assuming that Test has no package

```
C:\JenaAdapter\Jar> java -classpath ./../examples;pqr.jar;tvs.jar;abc.jar;123.jar;xyz.jar Test
```

Answer (score -1):

double-check the definition of your main method, if it's not public static void main (String[]) then the JRE is not going to find it to start